How can I Hide rows that are blank in specified columns, then export to PDF?
Overview: The Google Sheets file contains 3 sheet tabs. For each sheet tab, the following conditions have been identified to hide rows that have no value/blank in a specified range.
Conditions for sheet tabs:

example 01: If columns C, D and E are empty, Hide row
example 02: If columns C, D and E are empty, Hide row
example 03: If columns B, G, I, K, and M are empty, Hide row

After the specified rows are hidden, the Google sheets file is exported to PDF and attached in an email.
Current issue: It appears that the current script is hiding rows within each sheet tab of the Google sheets file, but when the file is exported to pdf and attached to an email, the rows that were set to hidden in the Google Sheets are still displayed in the PDF. It seems that the file is being converted to pdf prior to any hide row actions.
// Send email after Course Completion Form submit
function afterSubmit_Email(e)
{

  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))
  var email = e.namedValues['Email Address'][0]
  var name  = e.namedValues['First and Last Name'][0]
  Logger.log("the sumbitted email address = "+email)

  var rr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Reference");
  var theValues = rr.getRange("E2:F").getValues();
  var breakfastValues = theValues.filter(x => x[0]== email);

      var finalArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < breakfastValues.length; i++) {
        var form_id = breakfastValues[i].filter(item => (Number.isFinite(item) && item.id !== 0) || !Object.is(item, email));
        finalArray.push(form_id);
    }
    console.log(finalArray.filter(item => item != ''));


          //function hide_example01() {
            var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
            var sh = ss.getSheetByName("example 01");
            var vs = sh.getRange(3, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 2, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
            sh.showRows(3, 10);
            vs.forEach((r, i) => {
              if (r[2] === '' && r[3] === '' && r[4] === '') {
                sh.hideRows(i + 3);
              }
            });
          //}


          //function hide_example02() {
            var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
            var sh = ss.getSheetByName("example 02");
            var vs = sh.getRange(3, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 2, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
            sh.showRows(3, 10);
            vs.forEach((r, i) => {
              if (r[2] === '' && r[3] === '' && r[4] === '') {
                sh.hideRows(i + 3);
              }
            });
          //}



          //function hide_example03() {
            var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
            var sh = ss.getSheetByName("example 03");
            var vs = sh.getRange(3, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 2, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
            sh.showRows(3, 10);
            vs.forEach((r, i) => {
              if (r[1] === '' && r[4] === '' && r[6] === '' && r[8] === '' && r[10] === ''&& r[12] === '') {
                sh.hideRows(i + 3);
              }
            });
         // }


  Logger.log(form_id);
  Logger.log(pdfFile);

  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + form_id + '/';
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById("1znETuc02cx1XuBdB_rk9XTmAhYrfxfgn");  // Modified
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();


  // PDF file Formatting settings:
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
  + '&size=letter'      // paper size
  + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&top_margin=0.00'              //All four margins must be set!
  + '&bottom_margin=0.00'           //All four margins must be set!
  + '&left_margin=0.00'             //All four margins must be set!
  + '&right_margin=0.00'            //All four margins must be set!
  + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
  + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
  + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  var options = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, options);
  var pdfFile = response.getBlob().setName("Dummy file" + '.pdf');
  folders.createFile(pdfFile);

     Logger.log(url);


// Send Email 
GmailApp.sendEmail(email,"Test","Testing" + name +",Test", {
  attachments: [pdfFile],
  name: 'Testing Name'
});
   Logger.log(pdfFile);
}

Dummy spreadsheet

Can you add SpreadsheetApp.flush(); after the script hides the rows before var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + form_id + '/';? I'm guessing that the reason why the rows that were set to hidden in the Google Sheets are still displayed in the PDF is because the conversion captures the spreadsheet while the rows are being hidden while adding flush() waits before it Applies all pending Spreadsheet changes.

Thanks @Saddles as this was very helpful. The result is now functioning as expected. Thanks
